# Array initialization, too many initializer values

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I am defining a member variable like this:

```
float m_Colors[4];
```

In the constructor I want to initialize it like this:

```
m_Color = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
```

Even though I have done this a million times before on this particular occasion I get the error "too many initializer values". How could on these two very simple lines of code possibly be something wrong? Please englighten me.

Comment: `m_Colors` <-> `m_Color`? Please show your exact code (a [mcve]).

Comment: Note that you could do that with a `std::array` for example, not a C-like array.

Comment: You can't use the `=` syntax in the constructor iirc

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reinitialize the array again with the initializer syntax (it was already default initialized when the `class` was constructed).

You can use the use a `ctor` `initializer list` to initialize the `array` when the `class` is constructed.

```
struct S 
{
    S( ) 
      :  floats_{ 1.0f, 2.2f, 3.3f, 4.4f } 
    {  }

private:
    float floats_[ 4 ];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want use initializer for built in array, you must do when declare it.
Otherwise you can use like this in your constructor:

```
float tmp[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
memcpy_s(m_Colors, 4, tmp, 4);
```

Comment: Seems way to complicated but it would do the job. I have chosen to use an initializer list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::array<...> as datatype for your member. This way you can initialise it with curly-braces and also assign it this way if needed plus you get some additional modern C++ benefits.

```
#include <array>

class Object
{
public:
    Object() : m_Colors{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}
    {
    }

private:
    std::array<float, 4> m_Colors;
};
```

If you need to reassign:

```
void reinit()
{
    m_Colors = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
}
```